# TFS2018 tries to publish my Database

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have setup a Build Agent for TFS2018.
For our website project I have created a Builddefinition based on ASP.NET Website template.

During the buildprocess the agent tries to publish a database,
starting with the following steps:

> GetMSDeployInstalledVersionPath:   $(_DefaultMSDeployMaxVersion) is 3 
>   $(_MSDeployVersionsToTry) is 9.0   $(MSDeployPath) is C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\ ProcessPublishDatabaseSettings:
>   Starting Web deployment task from source: dbFullSql(******) to
>   Destination: dbFullSql(******). C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets(55,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Cannot connect to the database
>   'XXXX'. Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.)

The problem is, i do not want to publish any database and I not know why the build agent tries to publish a database.
I do not know from where he has the (wrong) information about the database.

In our solution, I do not have checked any of the deploy checkboxes for the configured configuration.

In our erlier TFS2015 Version, the build with xaml Definitions did not publish a database. I have not added something about a database in my  definition. For this reason, I think, the process fin something in one of the projects about a database and think he should publish a database.

How I can remove the publishing database step?

Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the cause:
In the web project settings, you will find a package web sql pane, where the deployment of a database was configured.

To this day, I had not noticed this setting option.

I have removed and now, I can devote myself to the next deployment error :-)